# Batch tf.data.Dataset.filter()?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I know one can filter a dataset with [`tf.data.Dataset.filter()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#filter):

```
d = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1, 2, 3])

d = d.filter(lambda x: x < 3)  # ==> [1, 2]

# `tf.math.equal(x, y)` is required for equality comparison
def filter_fn(x):
  return tf.math.equal(x, 1)

d = d.filter(filter_fn)  # ==> [1]
```

What if I want to do a "batch filter"? By this, I mean given a batch of strings `['str1', 'str2', 'str3', 'str4']`, how do I make a dataset that is able to return me a filtered dataset that spits out a batch of values that correspond to those strings: `[val1_respects_str1, val2_respects_str2, val3_respects_str3, val4_respects_str4]`?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not a filter but a map. The map function will compute the mapped values, such as:

```py
d = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(list(range(100)))

def map_fn(x):
  return x*2  # if you need arbitrary python logic, use tf.py_function to wrap it

d = d.shuffle(100).batch(10).map(map_fn)
```